# How many combinations are possible when rolling all Platonic solid dice?

Tags: probability, dice

I bought a set of five platonic solid dice  and I'm wondering  how many combinations exist if you roll them all at once.  Thanks for your help

Platonic solid dice are:
4, 6, 8, 12, 20 sided

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4\times6\times8\times12\times20=46080$$

That's an application of the [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: The game in developing,  The dates are rolled one at a time, in any order.

Comment: the order does not matter

Comment: The game I am ideveloping the 5 dice are rolled one at a time, in any order.  Rolling Three '3's consecutively is an instant win --  I wonder what the odds of that are on average.  The d20 will be the most likely 1st Dice -  but not always.  The odds of us depend on the order in which the player chooses to roll the five dice.  Thanks